# import scripts getting a URL/path to itself?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a feeling this is impossible but is there any way for an es6 imported script to get any kind of path to itself or if nothing else to know the domain that it was downloaded from?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to print a warning if the user includes a script from my library's site

```
// usercode.js
import foolib from 'https://foolib.org/dist/foolib.js';
```

```
// foolib.js

if (location.hostname !== 'foolib.org' && selfurl.hostname === 'foolib.org') {
  console.warn(`referencing this code directly from foo.com is garanteed to break.
     Use your own copy or a versioned CDN`);
}
```

Note that with script tags there is no formal way but a script can scan all the existing script tags and see if there is a reference to a script on a domain it cares about

```
if (location.hostname !== 'foolib.org' &&
    [...document.querySelectorAll('script')].findIndex(
        s => s.src === 'https://foolib.org/dist/foolib.js'
    ) >= 0) {
  console.warn('...');
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to do the same for es6 modules if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this information from the [`import.meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta) object:

```html
<script type="module">
  console.log( import.meta );
</script>
```